# Implement Substance Painter features in Blender

Tags: texture-painting

I have seen many substance painter videos on YouTube and I’m totally impressed with how much artistic freedom that software gives when it comes to texture painting.
I use Blender even for texture painting knowing fully well that it’s nowhere near Substance Painter. I use Blender because I can’t afford Substance Painter. I have seen that some Substance features like masking and layers for instance can be implemented in Blender (a workaround but same result). And it’s been very helpful.

Now I want to know if I can implement Filter (on mask and layer) that Substance Painter offers in Blender. Can I implement masking by colour ID in Blender?

Comment: You can check out the add-ons that exist to see how they fit in the workflow - BPainter for instance has a very powerful layering and masking system, and there are some others listed here https://cgcookie.com/articles/top-10-shading-and-texturing-addons-for-blender-2-8

Comment: You may also look at Layer Painter addon to see how they used their approach to using procedural textures to make the most out of masking for PBR materials https://blendermarket.com/products/layerpainter

Comment: @Craig can you please help me learn blender texture painting and procedural texturing and shading? And tutorial exclusively for this. Because I am completely at zero level at nodes and procedural texturing.

Comment: You can check out my old youtube channel, but be advised that my won add-ons don't work in 2.8+ anymore and not I'm not likely to ever pursue them again since improvements are coming that negate the need for them. https://www.youtube.com/user/artistCDMJ/videos?view_as=subscriber